# How can I validate a select field with a bound object in TYPO3?

Tags: forms, validation, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

Maybe my question is not really clear, so here are the details. I have created the two classes "Product" and "Offer" and want to pass a product object to a product property of an offer object, which is representing a select field.

The list view contains all the products which are linked to the page with the offer form.

List.html:

```
...
<f:for each="{products}" as="product">
    <div class="product-block">
        <f:link.page additionalParams="{product: product}" pageUid="11" section="form">
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
            ...
        </f:link.page>
    </div>
</f:for>
...
```

So I can pass the product to the offer form. The offer form contains a select field which uses this product information for preselection.

Offer.html:

```
...
<f:form action="send" method="post" additionalParams="{product: product}" name="offer" object="{offer}">

    <fieldset>
        <f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'offer.product'}"/>
        <f:form.hidden property="product" />
        <f:form.select
            property="product"
            options="{productOptions}"
            optionValueField="key"
            optionLabelField="value"
            prependOptionValue="0"
            prependOptionLabel="Choose your product"
        />
    </fieldset>

    ...

    <f:form.submit value="Send" />
</f:form>
...
```

This works great so far, but if you can see I have added a prepend option value, too. If someone don't choose a value and try to submit the offer form I getting the follwing error message:

**"#1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "": PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Offer::setProduct()
must be an instance of Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Product, null given ..."**

The product property of my offer model own a not empty validation annotation:

```
/**
 * Stores the product relation
 * 
 * @var \Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Product
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $product = null;
```

I thought this not empty validation is enough and will catch the null value, but it doesn't seems so.

In addition my offer action looks like this:

```
public function offerAction(\Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Offer $offer = null)
{
    $productId = intval(GeneralUtility::_GP('product'));
    $products = $this->productRepository->findAll();

    if ($productId > 0 && $this->productRepository->exists($productId)) {
        $product= $this->objectManager->get(
            'Fox\\Example\\Domain\\Model\\Product'
        );
        $product = $this->productRepository->findByUid($productId);
        $offer->setProduct($product);
    }

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $option = new \stdClass();
        $option->key = $product->getUid();
        $option->value = $product->getName();
        $productOptions[] = $option;
    }

    $this->view->assignMultiple([
        'offer' => $offer,
        'productOptions' => $productOptions
    ]);
}
```

Did I forgot something or how can I solve this issue?

**Update**

If I change the setter function of my product property of the offer model from

```
/**
 * Sets the product
 * 
 * @param \Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Product $product
 * @return void
 */
public function setProduct(\Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Product $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

to

```
/**
 * Sets the product
 * 
 * @param \Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Product $product
 * @return void
 */
public function setProduct($product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

then the not empty validator is working, but is this solution ok or bad or do I need a custom validator if not empty validator is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with placeholder values in select boxes.
What i did was to set the Model parameter from Setter function to null.

Try this code ...

```
/**
 * Sets the product
 * 
 * @param \Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Product $product
 * @return void
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
public function setProduct(\Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Product $product = null)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

Also, set validate annotation as notEmpty, in case this is a required field.

I hope that this helps you.